# Terraform CLI switch for auto-discarding pending runs

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

Sometimes when I `terraform apply`, it reports that there are pending runs, and they need to be resolve before I can continue:

```
To view this run in a browser, visit:
https://app.terraform.io/app/ORGNAME/WORKSPACENAME/runs/run-RUNID

Waiting for 9 run(s) to finish before being queued...
Waiting for 9 run(s) to finish before being queued... (30s elapsed)
```

I can do this by opening the URL and clicking "Discard all past runs". In the context I'm working, it is often safe to do so.

- Is there a switch I can pass to `apply` to tell it to just discard them without asking me?
- Failing that, is there a CLI command for just discarding runs, so I can run that before `apply`?
- Failing that, are there commands I can use to write my own "discard runs and apply" script?

Comment: This happens when you run terraform from the CLI? If not, please add an appropriate tag.

Comment: @MarkoE It does - what would the appropriate tag be?

Comment: Where is the URL coming from then?

Comment: @MarkoE I'm confused about what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: Quote: "can do this by opening the given URL and clicking "Discard all past runs". Which URL? I am not aware of any URLs when using the open source version of terraform.

Comment: Ah, got it - it must be specific to Terraform cloud. I added an example, maybe I can find a better tag.

Comment: Yup, that's why I was asking about the tag in the first place. :)